# Can form processor use postcode to derive state?

Tags: form-processor, action-provider

Rock and a hard place:
Using gravity forms to collect address with autocomplete results in corrupted state/province names as users override the auto complete & can't spell.
Or using gravity forms without address autocomplete - with dropdowns for country & state upsets our fundraising team as they love autocomplete.

So, just wondering if form processor can do something like:

```
If postcode = 3*** state = Victoria
            = 4*** state = Queensland
```

Only 8 states to choose from

Thanks all

Comment: off topic (slightly) addressfinder.nz covers AU so the whole address is an autocomplete (at a small monthly price)

Comment: Cheers Pete - $55 per month too steep for us!

Comment: Pricing depends on usage. IIRC it can be much lower than that (NZ$19). But not pushing it, just flagging it as an option

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Set Value action? So say for example the first action would set the value state to Victoria and have the condition input postcode = 3 etc.?

Comment: Sounds good ErikH but I'm not sure I have the form processor chops.

Comment: I have added a Set Value called State. My condition is compare parameter value. Configuration is value = 3000 and comparison is greater than or =. My parameter is Input::postcode. But what do I put in "Map output data if condition is not valid"? I'll put screendump as answer

Comment: Just leave that empty, it gives you the possibility to enter a value of the condition is not met which in some cases is useful. But you do not have to :-)

Answer (score 0):

not an answer - refer to comment
[image]